# Does Big Query SQL UDF structure allow complex logic as those in java script UDF?

Tags: google-bigquery

By using JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION customGreeting(a STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var d = new Date();
  if (d.getHours() < 12) {
    return 'Good Morning, ' + a + '!';
  } else {
    return 'Good Evening, ' + a + '!';
  }

""";
```

Is this flexible processing allowed in sql UDF? I didn't seem to find any example on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions inside SQL UDFs as well to achieve the same functionality, e.g.:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION customGreeting(a STRING) AS (
  IF(CURRENT_TIME() < '12:00:00',
     CONCAT('Good Morning, ', a, '!'),
     CONCAT('Good Evening, ', a, '!'))
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Elliott . Does it support multiple line statement and other flow control such as if , then else, for/while loop which are found in Oracle PL-SQL, SQL Server T-SQL and JavaScript?

Comment: You cannot use *procedural* statements within a SQL UDF. The body of it needs to be an expression.

Comment: @ZhangAllen you can accept Elliot's answer if it solved your doubt